# JBOSS incompatible for gwt2.3

Tags: java, gwt, jboss6.x

iam using jboss6.0 final version and GWT2.3 version .

I am getting an error:

> [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSE13Factory: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not deploying `gwt-dev.jar` or `gwt-user.jar` to your JBoss server. If you use GWT-RPC, you'll have to deploy `gwt-servlet.jar`; and if you use RequestFactory, you'll deploy `gwt-servlet-deps.jar` in addition to `gwt-servlet.jar` (provided you're not using Maven, otherwise you'll let Maven handle the dependencies for you, and `gwt-servlet-deps.jar` only bundles other *artifacts* for easy deployment, similarto `gwt-dev.jar` bundles Jetty and Tomcat for easy development)

Comment: When i removed gwt-dev.jar and gwt-user.jar iam getting different errors like

Comment: Thomas --> When i removed gwt-dev.jar and gwt-user.jar iam getting different errors like – 1)ERROR [ReadOnlyAccessFilter] Failed to init ReadOnlyAccessFilter: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: jboss:service=NamingBeanImpl is not registered.2)ERROR [[/invoker]] Exception starting filter ReadOnlyAccessFilter: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to init ReadOnlyAccessFilter